# What does `PAGE_ALIGN` do to and `unsigned int`? shouldn't it get an address?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, framebuffer

In some framebuffer configuration code I had seen these lines:

```
static unsigned int max_size = 0;

max_size = max(max_size, 8*(mi->xres * (mi->xres + mi->yres)));
    }

max_size = PAGE_ALIGN(max_size);
```

What does `PAGE_ALIGN` do to and `unsigned int`? shouldn't it get an address?

```
mi is `struct fb_videomode *`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It rounds the size up to an exact multiple of the page size (often something like 4k, though implementation-dependent).

In this case, it's not applying to an absolute address, but instead to a size - which will likely become a difference between addresses.